# Angular2: IFrame not loading as expected

Tags: angular, iframe

It is a very simple application with a toolbar and full-screen iframe below that. Everything was working fine until I started setting iframe `src` dynamically. Here is the code:
**app.component.html**

```
<md-toolbar class="toolbar">
  <span>Toolbar</span>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <button md-button (click)="updateDashboard(first_url)"  id="first" class="top-link">First Button</button>
  <button md-button  (click)="updateDashboard(second_url)" id="second" class="top-link">Second Button</button>
</md-toolbar>


<iframe id="report-frame" frameborder="0" [src]="dashboardUrl"></iframe>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  dashboardUrl: SafeUrl;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  private first_url: string = "https://www.google.com/"
  private second_url:string="https://reddit.com"
  updateDashboard(url: string) {
    this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Try like this in updateDashboard method - `this.dashboardUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);`

Comment: No luck...still seeing the same issue.